# Asp.net core 3 middleware just for non-static file requests

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, middleware

I have a middleware and I load user data (DealerId) from the database and add it to the `context.items` to be able to access `DealerId` in all my actions later on.

here is my middleware:

```
public class LoadUserData
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    public LoadUserData(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, UserManager<MehvarIdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var carNegarUser = await userManager.GetUserAsync(context.User);
            context.Items["DealerId"] = carNegarUser.DealerId;
        }
        await _next(context);

    }
}
```

my problem is that for every request such as requests for static files my middleware's `Invoke` method is called.

Is there any way to enable the `Invoke` method to be called just for non-static files requests?

Comment: could you show your `Configure` method from `Startup` class?
How is the `app.UseStaticFiles();` registered? - before of after using your custom middleware?
It might just matter of the order your have applied them